# Why are some Google Sheets API v4 functions not documented?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to understand how the [Google Sheet API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) works, so I check the sample codes provided by Google for the API methods. When looking at the examples for Google Apps Script (e.g. [`batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate)), I find this method, `Sheets.newUpdateSpreadsheetPropertiesRequest()`, and many more - all beginning with the prefix `new`. I've searched, but I can't find these methods described anywhere in the documentation.

This is for me not as clear as the behavior of the Spreadsheet Service (`SpreadsheetApp`).

Have I missed something, or is the REST API not well-documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Advanced Service APIs are wrappers for their corresponding REST APIs. Methods prefixed with `new` are constructors for the corresponding resource object in the respective API (used mainly for auto-completion).

For example `Sheets.newUpdateSpreadsheetPropertiesRequest()` is equivalent to the [`UpdateSpreadsheetPropertiesRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateSpreadsheetPropertiesRequest) object. It takes a bit of getting used to, but spend some time navigating the documentation. It will begin to make sense eventually.

Comment: ok thank you but is there anymore stuff not written I should know or `new`prefix is the only thing that is not in the doc?

Comment: @JSmith On the apps script side you're going to rely heavily on its autocomplete features to see whats what. However, the apps script methods and objects are always analogous to some url endpoint or resource listed in the REST API. So you'll have to leverage both.